# Jinja2 Like View Templating Approach for Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

Which Spring MVC compatible templating engine will allow me to achieve Python's Jinja2 like templates?

Example:

A template file which all views extend with their own content

main.jinja2:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
...
```

Each view only has to customise some of the template's defined blocks

a_view.jinja2:

```
{% extends "main.jinja2" %}
{% block title %}A View Page Title{% endblock %}
```

I do not require syntax compatibility, only this concept of extending a base template.

One possible solution is to invert the JSP templating approach.

Create a main.jsp, all controllers will render main.jsp for their view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><jsp:include page="titles/${title_inc}.jsp" /></title>
...
```

From the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome( ModelMap args ) {
    args.addAttribute("title_inc", "home");
    args.addAttribute("body_inc", "home");
    args.addAttribute("message", "A Message!");
    return "main";
}
```

I am hopeful it would be possible to refine this approach, i would prefer to infer the correct name of the title / body includes from some session attribute rather than specify them in the model map for each controller.

I have reservations about performance. I do not know if the main.jsp is cached (for performance reasons), but this approach effectively negates most benefits of caching the results of rendering main.jsp. If caching does happen this approach may not even work if there is no way to invalidate the cached copy.

Still seeking a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home) will do what you are asking...

You can define as many "layouts" as you need but they do not inherit from each other. Individual pages get their content inserted into the layout you choose for them.

If you need proper inheritance of templates (including abstract templates), then you need to look at [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/). Tiles is more powerful but also more complicated and is harder to maintain in the long term IMHO.

Comment: I investigated Tiles, but found that current versions are not trivial to implement with Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to replicate Jinj2 like templating with JSP & JSTL.

Each controller refers to the appropriate view as would be expected (which is an improvement on my first attempt above):

a_view.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="pageTitle" scope="request">My Title</c:set>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp" %>
```

main.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><c:out value="${pageTitle}" /></title>
...
```

This appears to be more or less exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Seems like you reinventing the wheel... IMHO its a mistake to try and re-implement a technology from Python into a Java/Spring app (I went through the same thing when going from Perl to Java). Embrace the new technology and research/learn the new tools/libraries. Sitemesh does this + much more. E.g. individual pages are proper HTML JSP pages so your IDE can provide code completion and syntax correction. It has functionality to inject values into menus and crumbtrails, etc.

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty reasonable. The reason for wanting templating is to provide breadcrumb navigation.